# Сортировка по 2м столбцам в mysql

Tags: mysql

пишу вывод товаров магазина. Необходимо сделать вывод чтоб впереди были товары в наличии, потом не в наличии. И те и другие шли по возрастании цены. Как в примере ниже. Поля типа int

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | quantity  | price |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | 15        |     7 |
|  2 | 8         |    12 |
|  3 | 64        |    15 |
|  4 | 0         |     2 |
|  5 | 0         |     4 |
|  6 | 0         |     6 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать это в mysql.

Comment: `ORDER BY quantity  ASC, price ASC`?

Comment: `ORDER BY quantity = 0, price`

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Второй вариант помог